# Elasticsearch: Unable to do range and script query on the same field

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to do a query which has range and script operations on a field,
I am able to run the query only if use either of the range or script operation, but not together.

**Following is the query -**

```
GET /listings/_search
{
    "query": {
        "range" : {
            "forecast_quantity" : {
                 "gte" : 250
            }
        },
        "constant_score": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "script": {
                            "script": {
                                "source": "doc['forecast_quantity'].value > doc['minimum_quantity'].value",
                                "params": {}
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Following the data the I have -**

```
{
    "took": 0,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 2,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 1.0,
        "hits": [{
                "_index": "listings",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "listing_id": 2,
                    "forecast_quantity": 222,
                    "minimum_quantity": 200
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "listings",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "3",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "listing_id": 3,
                    "forecast_quantity": 333,
                    "minimum_quantity": 300
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**I am getting the following error -**

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "[range] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",
        "line": 8,
        "col": 7
      }
    ],
    "type": "parsing_exception",
    "reason": "[range] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",
    "line": 8,
    "col": 7
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

**Reference -**
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html

Comment: I can see that the constant score query is used for boosting. Do you want to boost the results that match with that particular part?

Comment: I used `constant_score` to wrap the filter and term queries

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add more than one condition to your query, try to do it with a Boolean query, specificaly with a `filter`. I can think of the following:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "filter" : [
                {
                    "range" : {
                        "forecast_quantity" : {
                            "gte" : 250
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "script" : {
                        "script" : {
                            "source": "doc['forecast_quantity'].value > doc['minimum_quantity'].value",
                            "lang": "painless"
                         }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Also `must` should work, but I'm more used to `filter`.

Hope this is helpful! :D

Comment: just for my knowledge, why is it like in some cases, it's `query > filter > bool` and in others `query > bool > filter`? And if I have to do `Range and Script` then it has to be under `filter` is it, I could not add must under `bool`?

Comment: I think that's more related to style. But I haven't seen any query > filter > bool. Can you share with me any example of that? I haven't found any in the docs

Comment: for the `constant_score` query, it was `query > filter > bool`

Comment: You're right. I can think again of styles. There should no be much difference from each other since they should work the same way.

Comment: 'Filter' works as 'must' so maybe having query > filter > bool > must might be more confusing to read or to maintain. I wouldn't recommend that structure.